# Como contar las palabras en una frase determinada por el usuario Python

Tags: python-3.x, bucles

Hola buenas tarde soy principiante en programación soy autodidacta por lo que no cuento con un profesor al cual dirigirme decidí sumergirme en mi primer lenguaje y Python fue el que me intereso, actualmente estoy leyendo un libro que contiene problemas para resolver sin embargos a veces sus ejercicios son un poco difíciles de acuerdo a la lección (por que hay funciones o cosas que no te explica)

Entonce al querer contar las palabras solo me las divide me podrian orientar a como puedo contar las palabras de la oracion

posdata: Eh visto en foros que la mayoria de los codigos los definen con funciones aun no aprendo hacerlo por lo que me disculpo si mi codigo se ve mal

El ejercicio es el siguiente

A) Leer una frase y determinar cuantas palabras tiene

```
   #Inicio del Ejercisio
print("===================================================================================")
print("Taller de repaso ejercisio 14 leccion 5")
print("===================================================================================")

#Descripcion del ejercisio
print("Leer una frase y determinar cuantas palabras tiene")
print("===================================================================================")

oracion = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
palabras = oracion.split()
count = 0

for i in oracion:
    if i == palabras:
        count =+ count+1
        print(count)
print(palabras)
```

Comment: En lugar del `for` podrías utilizar `print(len(palabras))`. Tampoco necesitas el `count`

Comment: El operador correcto es `+=` y en tu caso deberías hacer `count += 1` que es lo mismo a `count = count + 1`. Además, quita ese `if` que siempre te dará `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una oración está compuesta de palabras y espacios entre ellas.

La función `split` existe en casi todos los lenguajes y lo que hace es retornar una lista de palabras según un argumento que indica cual es divisor, generalmente harías un `string.split(" ")` diciendo que te divida el string por un espacio, no obstante Python tiene la particularidad de que si pones string.split(), es decir sin argumentos, también te lo divide por espacios, pero sin contar los espacios iniciales, finales ni espacios consecutivos, es decir es aún mejor para tu caso, ya que:   `esto serían     cuatro  palabras`

Entonces tú tienes

```
oracion = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
palabras = oracion.split()
count = 0
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero después pones:

```
for i in oracion:
```

Esto está mal, porque tú quieres recorrer `palabras`. Recorrer `oración` es ir letra por letra que no te sirve para nada

luego tienes

```
if i == palabras:
```

Esto no tiene sentido y tampoco nunca se cumplirá, porque estas comparando una letra con una lista de palabras

y luego tienes

```
count =+ count+1
```

Este `+` que le pusiste no hace nada, es lo mismo que poner `count = count+1` y esto se puede resumir poniendo `count += 1` que es lo que creo que quisiste poner (estaban invertidos los smbolos)

Tu código queda así:

```
oracion = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
palabras = oracion.split()
count = 0

for i in palabras:
    count+=1
print(count)
```

Ahora bien, en Python está la función [len](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp) para determinar el largo de una lista, así que incluso puedes poner

```
oracion = input("Ingrese una oracion: ")
palabras = oracion.split()
print(len(palabras))
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme, tu ultima explicación del código es una manera sencilla de ahorrar tiempo, sin embargo agradezco que corrigieras mi ejercicio con el bucle de for debido ah que a si me lo pedía el ejercicio, muchas gracias por la atención y mucho éxito también.